# How to pass props properly through Link in ReactJS so that it can be opened in new tab also?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass props through Link like this: `<Link to={{ pathname:'/agent/details', user: {uid: {id}}}}>View Account History</Link>` This is working fine and the props is received in the target page as `this.props.location.user.uid.id`
But when I tried to open the Link object (View Account History) in this case in the new tab or using ctrl+click , somehow the props is not getting passed.

Comment: When you open the app in a new tab, you're essentially opening a new version of the frontend. No front-end state is preserved for you. If you're really concerned about these props being conserved, consider passing them in the URL as parameters

Comment: Yeah, thought of passing it in the URL as parameter. But in this case the prop is id of the user which is eventually used to fetch some backend data. So, it might be quite inappropriate to show sensitive info in the URL. Also the URL might be too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data you want to pass in localStorage. Passing data in URL would make the URL too long.

Comment: Sorry, if I am wrong, I am quite new to react. But in this case the id prop that I am passing is dynamic. So can we update the localStorage every time the Link object is clicked? If yes, how can that be done?